# Toast.makeText(...).show() is sometimes misaligned

Tags: android, alignment, toast, android-context

I am using Toast.makeText to display results from dialogs and having a slightly odd problem: the text is displaying above the frame that should hold it, like this:

The message is misaligned with the frame.  Please align it better.
[***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**]

I'm generally using code looking like

```
Toast bread = Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
bread.show();
```

from a dialog.  I've heard bad context can sometimes cause inflation problems but `getOwnerActivity()` is returning null, so that's out.  In any case, I would have thought getContext() would supply the context passed in at construction time, which is the activity anyway.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try changing getContext() with getApplicationContext()...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can try this:

```
Toast bread = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
bread.show();
```

Comment: Not available from within the Dialog class but would `getContext().getApplicationContext()` work?

Comment: It was written as a comment of question before you post this answer

Comment: @CrimsonChin Sorry, I would have marked it straight away but the thing makes you wait ten minutes and I forgot.

Answer (score 3):

```
bread.setGravity(5,5,5);
```

try playing around by changing those values till you get exact location.

But using `Gravity.CENTER` and other constants is the prefererrd way..

Answer (score 1):

If you create the toast from inside an activity you should use: `this` or `MyActivityName.this` as the context parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try using,

```
<supports-screens
   android:largeScreens="true"
   android:normalScreens="true"
   android:smallScreens="true"
   android:anyDensity="true" />
```

in your manifest file.